# nodejs express webapp - ERROR: read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, web-applications

When I leave my application idle for a few minutes, it errors out.  This is my first webapp I created and it is sending and receiving data from a mysql database - somewhat of a sign up form.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?  Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
       host: host,
       user: user,
       password: password,
       database: db,
       ssl: ssl
      
    });
```

My original code was var connection = mysql.createConnection...
I replaced that and removed connection.connect();

This seems to happen when establish a single use connection, it can be avoided by establishing a connection pool instead.